# SQL Anywhere 12 ODBC returns zero rows when using filters in query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, odbc, sybase

I'm building a .NET c# app that's connecting to my SQL Anywhere 12 Database to get data using the ODBC driver but i have a weird problem that whenever i use a filter in the query i get nothing in the reader but if i do the same query in Sybase Center i get the expected results ..

this is an example of my code

```
 connection = new OdbcConnection(conStrMonitor);
 connection.Open();

var cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select art_artnr, art_ben from monitor.ARTIKEL WHERE art_artnr='VSV203798'", connection);


        var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            SearchArticleNr article = new SearchArticleNr();
            article.Article = sdr["art_artnr"].ToString();
            article.Ben = sdr["art_ben"].ToString();
            SarticleList.Add(article);
        }
```

reader loop does not trigger and when i look at sdr.hasrows it's set as false

[Using the same query in Sybase Central](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8E0z.png)

i tried other filters for example LIKE and the same problem occurs then, i'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

reference used for my app is System.Data.Odbc

Comment: does the connection uses the an user that can query that table ? have you tried without the WHERE ?

Comment: Are there no error or state infos available?

Comment: yeah if you remove where it will list the content of the table

Comment: are you sure there are matching records for WHERE art_artnr='VSV203798' then ?

Comment: yes :) see the screenshot from sybase central it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work but not using system.data.odbc. i found out about the iAnywhere .net reference that you can install into your project. i found mine under C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Assembly\v4.5 and i then added the reference to my project browsing to this folder and imported iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5.dll .. using this reference i now get results back even using filters in my queries.

here's the code now:

```
    public List<SearchArticleNr> SearchArticle(string articlenr)
    {
        List<SearchArticleNr> SarticleList = new List<SearchArticleNr>();
        iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection myConnection = null;
        iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand myCommand = null;
        iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SADataReader myDataReader = null;
        try
        {
            myConnection = new iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection(conStrMonitor);
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            myCommand.CommandText = "Select art_artnr, art_ben from monitor.ARTIKEL where art_artnr = ?";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@art", articlenr);
            myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int i = 0;
            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                i++;
                SearchArticleNr article = new SearchArticleNr();
                article.Article = myDataReader["art_artnr"].ToString();
                article.Ben = myDataReader["art_ben"].ToString();
                SarticleList.Add(article);
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                SearchArticleNr article = new SearchArticleNr();
                article.Article = "NO OBJECTS FOUND";
                article.Ben = "NO OBJECTS FOUND";
                SarticleList.Add(article);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            myConnection = null;
            throw exp;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            myDataReader.Close();
            myCommand = null;
        }
        return SarticleList.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never close connection. `var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);` or something like it (I havn't used ODBC in a long time so `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` may not be correct answer but you can google it). Then `while` will be hit.

Comment: the while loop triggers fine though if i remove the where clause and it lists the content of the table just fine

Comment: sorry didn't seen that. try to set 'VSV203798' as string (string a = 'VSV203798') and add it as parameter ("Select art_artnr, art_ben from monitor.ARTIKEL WHERE art_artnr={0}", a)